# Product Sku in custom module

Tags: sku

I've created an extension of the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price module where I will dynamically load prices from an external database.

I need the product sku in order to retrieve the correct price from my DB. I used 
`Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();`

but that doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Make sure you got the product is please check getid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at how Magento core modules calls product specific attributes like `$product->getData('price');` and found that  `$product->getData('sku');` worked perfectly!

FYI - I had to change my module and the above methods stopped working. I had to switch to $this->getSku();

Answer (score 1):

First check for PHP errors in your web server log.

If on Apache: http://www.codeasite.com/index.php/linux-a-apache/94-how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files

This might give you an indication of where the problem is at. Your `$_product` variable might not be defined or, it could be a conflict within an extension.

Also check the Magento system and exception logs - [if it is not enabled, enable it](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/203-troubleshooting-magento/enabling-system-and-exception-logging-in-magento) then you should be able to see the logs under `<magento base dir>/var/log`